# Receiving empty string on webhook request PHP

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest, webhooks

I am trying to pull customers info from webhook but I am receiving empty string when I try to print it. Here is my endpoint URL:
[image: image of webhook]

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$acion=json_decode($data,true);

var_dump($acion);
exit();
?>
```

I am getting NULL printed on my webpage. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling/testing the endpoint?

Comment: I think this line serves for that: $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
?

Comment: That line only says that your script is expecting a JSON-encoded request body, not how you are testing it. And NULL says that it isn't getting that JSON.

Comment: Well what should I do?

Comment: See my answer below and start learning about HTTP requests.

Comment: Before trying to `json_decode()` it, have you checked what `$data` looks like?  As already pointed out, just loading this endpoint yourself in your browser won't work, since you're not sending anything.  How are you actually testing it?  Does the service you are using in the screenshot allow you to send a dummy payload to the endpoint to test?

Comment: Hi, the var_dump on $data gives me string(0) "". I am creating payment form and when I make payment on separate page the JSON data is created on payments end but I am not sure how to payload the endpoint. The payment form is located on order.php page, do I need to point webhook to that page? How can I read data from webhook on website and on which page does the webhook need to point? Here is payments webhook page http://prntscr.com/22ny5o3

Comment: If `$data` is empty, obviously `$acion` is going to be empty, right? :-) I don't follow any of what you describe, but presumably you are building the webhook to handle a payload from your payment processer, eg Stripe or Paypal or whatever it is (I can see it is not either of those 2), right?  What does their documentation say?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is expecting a valid JSON-encoded request body, so you should test it accordingly. You cannot simply access the URL in your web browser, because there is no request body sent that way. Instead you need to use some tool which is capable sending such requests, e.g. Postman:

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, given the correct input, the output is also correct.

Comment: I will check it now in Postman. Can I access somehow in PHP data from endpoint because I need to print it on webpage? Thanks.

Comment: I need to receive customers information from payment provider and I am still getting NULL value in postman too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code.
The reason you getting NULL may be the data you are receiving is not in JSON format.
You can check that by printing $data variable without decoding it with `json_decode()`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

echo $data;
exit();
?>
```

And the second reason could be you are receiving data with a GET request. Then you can access data with `$_GET[]`.